# Link to file that opens in browser

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to provide a link to a gpg file on a webpage. Irrespective of relative path or absolute ([static asset](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling)), on clicking the link, the index page keeps re-appearing. I don't want to use js to read the contents of gpg and render that. Instead, I want the browser to handle opening of the file (either open or download). Not working with other file types as well.

I have tried adding webpack config for this particular file type (file-loader/url-loader). Using raw-loader I can read the contents of the file, but I don't need that. Tried adding the file as an import.

To reproduce, create new project with `vue-cli`. Add this to `App.vue` template: `<a href="/public/a.gpg">Link</a>`
Create `vue.config.js`:

```
    chainWebpack: config => {
      config.module
        .test(/\.gpg$/)
        .use('file-loader')
        .loader('file-loader')
        .end()
    }
  }
```

Kindly suggest a way to include links to file present on the same domain. I don't want the vue app to handle rendering of such files.

Comment: The `.gpg` files should probably not even be compiled/loaded by webpack, but placed in the `/public` folder to begin with? It is a static asset/resource that is not related to any business logic or view rendering, so it should probably not be in the `src` folder and shouldn't be built/compiled by webpack. Like how VueCli treats the `favicon.ico` file.

Comment: Just tried adding `<a href="/public/a.gpg">Link</a>` to `App.vue` without any config changes or scripts. Didn't work.

Comment: That's incorrect usage: [read up on the documentation on how to reference static assets in the public folder](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder). So you should probably use something like `<a :href="\`${publicPath}a.gpg\`">`

Comment: It is clearly stated: `If your app is not deployed at the root of a domain, you will need to prefix your URLs with the publicPath`. I was giving absolute path because I am using `npm run serve` to host it locally.

Comment: So I tried `<a :href="publicPath+'a.gpg'">Link</a>` and it worked. The absolute link did not work although I was hosting at the root of the domain. Also, the official way in the documentation did not work : `${publicPath}a.gpg`